# How can one tell if Nappa has become a Super Saiyan?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

We can identify Super Saiyans by the change in the colour of their hair.
With Nappa being bald, how could we identify he has become a Super Saiyan? Is it only by the increase in power?

Comment: maybe... just maybe he grows hair?

Comment: Just look at what the scouter says about his power.

Comment: I don't remember Nappa turning into a SSJ. When did that happen?

Comment: Joking answer: At SS1, Nappa loses his mustache and grows one yellow hair. At SS2, Nappa loses his eyebrows too and grows more hair. At SS3, Nappa loses all his hairs, while his head shines instead. Every 30 seconds, the shine will change from Red to Yellow, Yellow to Green, and Green to Red like a traffic light. LOL

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not only by hair.

[image: Goku SSJ]

As you can see, the eyebrows and eye color changes as well. So you'll be able to tell.

Comment: But what if he goes to Super Saiyan 3 or more?

Comment: @HariNandha: Well, since it hadn't happened, we can't tell for sure.

Comment: Also, SSJ seems to emit a yellow glow around the character (when they are powering up).

Comment: It could be possible that as goku's hair gets double the size at SSJ3, Nappa gets hair at SSJ3! :P

Comment: hair growing longer for Super Saiyan 3 is the result of it take hair from other places, Nappa will get hair but he becomes bold elsewhere

Comment: @HariNandha If nappa went SSJ3 he would lose his eyebrows. Not sure about the hair though

Answer (score 1):

As anime watchers, it's difficult for us to fully grasp how a character sees another character, and we have to understand how some react to others. When Freiza returns with his father and faces Trunks, he watches him become a Super Saiyan and shouts, "Those eyes! They have the same eyes!". This leads me to believe that the intensity of Ki energy seen through a transformed Saiyan's eyes is much more incredible than the solid blue-green circles that we see.

There is also the matter of aura, which is difficult to consider. We see a yellow, 2D arc over the character, but I can only imagine that to see one's aura intensify to a visible level, must be like watching them enveloped by fast moving, controlled flames.

These characteristics would surely be noticeable enough to see that he has transformed, but there is the playful idea that he could grow hair, much like Goku's SSJ3 form. However, I don't believe that with those gigantic muscles, Nappa could ever flow enough Ki through his entire body, without losing it at every nerve, to force his body to grow more hair. I see the Saiyan's hair serve only one purpose as a direct channel of Ki, and it grows when there is too much Ki for it to contain. With that said, I think Nappa's body doesn't allow efficient enough usage of Ki for him to need such a channel of Ki, nonetheless transform into the ultimate warrior form.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you remember what Freiza comments on seeing Trunk is not about the hair but its those saiyan eyes.

Apparently the pupil becomes green on the transformation.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

By looking at his eye brows and mustache if it is gold or if u see yellow super saiyn energy flair around nappa.

Comment: Includin the eyes

Answer (score 0):

By that time, there was no ''yellow hair'' yet so it probably wasn't a wild thought. Nappa has a small role in the DBZ series compared to Vegeta who is his companion but hey maybe Nappa has hair on other places. E.g. eyebrows.