# Who is this character from a Dragon Ball videogame?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

[image: Videogame]

The one in the right. I can read the first word in japanese says Vegita but I can't understand the rest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

べジータたちをたおせ *(Be-ji-i-ta-ta-chi-o ta-o-se)*, which means *"Defeat Vegita and his comrades"*.

By the appearance of SSJ3 Vegeta and Nappa, it's from the game [Dragon Ball Heroes](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Heroes), a Japanese arcade game developed by [Dimps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimps), which they have developed a lot of popular anime video games.

[image]

Comment: since this shows SSJ3 Nappa we can answer [how we can tell is Nappa is a Super Saiyan](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/6305/1587)

Comment: well you realized it, it should be your answer

Comment: @happy face didnt you mean Be-ji-i-ta-chi-ta-o-ta-o-se . I'm almost sure you are missing 2